# DbFit Connection for Remote Oracle Server via SSH

Tags: oracle, ssh, fitnesse, dbfit

**Please help me connecting to remote Oracle Server.**

Oracle 11g is hosted on a Unix Server, which we access

1. Creating a SSH session . See Attachment 'Remote Host Connection.jpg'[image]
2. Creating a SSH tunnel.. See attachment 'Tunneling.jpg'[image]

After the tunnel is established (2nd method), I though we should be able to establish connection from DbFit to DB server, but its not working. Connection timeout error is show.

Please help me to get the connection established

1. Either directly creating a SSH tunnel from DbFit if possible.
2. Or connect to DB server using the SSH tunnel created.

Below is the code used for testing

```
!path lib/*.jar
!|dbfit.OracleTest|

!|Connect|localhost:5000|<DB user name>|<password>|dbfit|

!|Query|select 'test' as x|
|x                        |
|test                     |
```

Please find attached screenshot with error displayed. [image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved.

It was problem with tunneling to the DB server and not with FitNesse.

Regards,
Kabilan